# open firefox with a profile path [selenium webdriver NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to open the default profile in firefox.
I have tried using:

```
options.setProfile(path);
```

but it didn't work

I have managed to open the profile using `options.addArguments()` but I couldn't control it.
it gives "permission denied" or "connection closed"

I'm using "selenium-webdriver 4.0.0-alpha.5" and "firefox 78.0.1 (64-bit)" on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I use this :

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

let options = new firefox.Options();
let profile = '/home/me/.mozilla/firefox/4p90s4py.oss';
options.setProfile(profile);


let driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .setFirefoxOptions(options)
        .build();
```

hopefully it helps